# How to make UISplitViewController in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, unrecognized-selector

I have read some tutorials from Apple and suggestions here, but I can't understand how to make a `UISplitViewController`. I have an app and it is working 100% to iPhone portrait (Landscape for iPhone is deactivated). iPad Portrait is working too but I need to show a view `UINavigationController` of a class called `ZIndexTableViewController` (in portrait I just call it using a button and using `modalPresentationStyle`).

Now, in iPad Lanscape I required to put `ZIndexTableViewController` on left side and a `UIView` (`ZPrismView` class called `PrismView`) as detailed view. I try to build just when the iPad is in landscape:

```
UISplitViewController *splitVC= [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitVC.viewControllers =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.indices,self.prismView, nil];
```

`PrismView` is initialized and `_indices` too. When I run the app the only error is thread 1: signal sigabrt; in console:

```
PrismApp[1408:48478] Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
2016-05-06 16:41:00.631 PrismApp[1408:48478] -[ZPrismView parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc89622cb0
2016-05-06 16:41:00.644 PrismLab[1408:48478] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ZPrismView parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffc89622cb0'
```

Comment: `self.prismView` isn't a `UIViewController`. You need to pass an array of view controllers to the `viewController` property of the split controller.

Comment: Thanks! now is working